# Unsure why I'm getting a syntax error when passing string to function

Tags: javascript, firebug

When I pass the string `2cdfdfa2-3639-4aed-bf37-9fb7ba1c936c` to a javascript function, I get syntax error in Firebug.

I have my code in a variable before inserting it into a div-tag. I print this out in the Console when I press the DeleteBookmarkFunction. Firebug says there is a syntax error in the call of the function:

```
<div onclick='DeleteBookmarkFunction('3fad79fb-ce54-4ceb-9b35-cfb50d5540de')'>
  <a class='remove'>Slett</a>
</div>
```

Some of my code:

```
var id=data[j].UniqueID;
src += "<div  id='" + data[j].UniqueID + "'></div>" ;

src += "<div onclick=\'DeleteBookmarkFunction  ( \'"
src += id;
src += "\' )\'>";
src += '<a class=\'remove\'>Slett</a></div>';
```

What is causing Firebug to report an error?

Comment: Hint: Look at the syntax highlighting in your question.

Comment: Your quotes are miss-matched, the single quotes inside the attribute value are breaking out of the attribute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes for attributes

```
<div onclick="DeleteBookmarkFunction  ( '3fad79fb-ce54-4ceb-9b35-cfb50d5540de' )"><a class="remove">Slett</a></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter which you use, just make sure the outer quotes are different from the inner ones.